# Function to get max texture size for OpenGL on Android (that can run on the UI thread)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've written the following function to get the max texture size on Android. The function should run on the UI thread and cannot assume that an EGLContext has been setup already.

It seems to work on my test device, but I'm fairly new to both OpenGl and Android, and I am not fully confident about the code. I relied on trial and error and some copy-pasting without fully understanding things.

Do you see any issues with the code? Specifically:

1. Is this robust? i.e. have I unknowingly made any bad assumptions?
2. Have I cleaned up resources correctly?
3. Can it be made simpler?

Here is the code (in Kotlin):

```
    private fun getGLMaxTextureSize():Int {
        // Get display.
        val display = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(0)

        // Choose config.
        val configSpec = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_NONE)
        val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1)
        var num_config = IntArray(1)
        EGL14.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, 0, configs, 0,1, num_config, 0)

        // Create context.
        val attribs = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE)
        val context = EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, configs[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attribs, 0)
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, context)

        // Read texture size.
        val intBuffer = IntArray(1)
        GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, intBuffer, 0)

        // Cleanup.
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
        EGL14.eglDestroyContext(display, context)

        return intBuffer[0]
    }
```

Comment: You're creating an OpenGLES 3 context. 37% of devices won't support that according to https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. Think you just have to change all the '3's to '2's to fix it (there are 3 in your code)

Comment: Noted and edited.